# Galaxy Camera records 320x480 video using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE Intent

Tags: android, camera, galaxy

I launch video capture intent on Galaxy Camera using below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // With and without this, it yields same resolution
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

and default video resolution turns out to be 320x240 @30fps. How do I change it to use highest possible video resolution i.e. 1920x1080

Comment: @ejo4041 have you faced it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change it to use highest possible video resolution i.e. 1920x1080

Use `MediaRecorder` directly. You cannot force a third-party camera app, whatever that app may be, to record at any particular resolution. While whatever app you are using *should* record at different resolutions for differing values of `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY`, there is no requirement that it do so.

Comment: Im using Galaxy camera's stock Camera app. Stock camera apps should respect it, No?

Comment: @Taranfx: In theory, they should respect it. In theory, I would have hair. :-)